# How to pass string from one Fragment to another?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs

I want to pass a string call custID from one fragement to anopther. but I don't know how to pass it. Below is my code:

```
class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public TabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch(i) {
            case 0: return MaterialUpConceptFakePage.newInstance();
            case 1: return MaterialUpConceptFakePage.newInstance();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch(position) {
            case 0: return "Tab 1";
            case 1: return "Tab 2";
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: you can use setArgument() method to pass values to Fragments

Comment: Look at the answer to your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments) in detail.

Comment: @CM Woo: You might be looking for passing data between fragments of view pager. check this links http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/06/communication-between-fragments-in.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492791/how-to-pass-a-string-between-fragments-in-a-viewpager

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("ID", "value");
MyFragment obj=new MyFragment ();
obj.setArguments(bundle);
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can use bundle as below -

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);

getFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.body, fragment, null)
.commit();
```

and then inside onCreateView() you can receive as below -

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
int myInt = bundle.getInt(key, defaultValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

User `Bundle` to pass any value from one `Fragment` to another. This is how you can pass string from one `Fragment` to another.

**Put the value**

```
SecondFragment secondFragment = new SecondFragment ();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("MyKey", "MyValue");
secondFragment.setArguments(args);
```

**Load the second fragment**

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, secondFragment).commit();
```

**In onCreateView of the second Fragment:**

```
//Retrieve the value
String value = getArguments().getString("MyKey");
```

Answer (score 0):

While a simple Bundle like other answers works, I can already see you use the newInstance so I will show you an example while still using newInstance to make the code easier to maintain in the future.

In your fragment where you want the String to be add this code

```
 public static YourFragmentName newInstance(String str) {
        YourFragmentName fragment = new YourFragmentName ();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable("customer_id", str);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

Then looking at your code instead of

```
MaterialUpConceptFakePage.newInstance()
```

you should have

```
MaterialUpConceptFakePage.newInstance(customerid)
```

Then inside your onCreateView

```
String customer_id = (String) getArguments().get("customer_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreference is a good way for passing data between activities or fragment. You can send any data int,boolean, string  int etc.

```
SharedPreferences preference;
  //Initialize preference

preference = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("STATE",MODE_PRIVATE);
  // it uses key-value pairs
 // put string data to preference
    preference.edit().putString("Your_String_Data", "anything").commit();

//use this to get that value in any fragment.
 preference = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("STATE",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  String data  = preference.getString("Your_String_Data",null);
```